# Why is the program terminating before scanning an input?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I am very new in programming. The code I was trying is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, a = 1, c = 5;
    char ch;
    do
    {
        printf("Type the last number of the series 5 * 10 * 15 * ... * N:");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for( ; c <= n; a = a*c, c = c +5);
        {
            printf("The result is %d\nDo you want do it again? (Type 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no)", a);
            ch = getchar();
        }
    }
    while(ch=='y');
    return 0;
}
```

But the problem is the program is being executed without asking Y or N. The loop is not working. The loop works just fine if I use `while(a=a);` instead. What's wrong?

Comment: Do you mean I should remove that '\n'? Doesn't solve anyway

Comment: The `'\n'` is the <Enter> from your first text entry.  Say you typed `1`, `5`, `<Enter key>`.  That 3rd keystroke is still in `stdin` after `scanf()` completes to be consumed (read) by `ch = getchar();`

Comment: Why all the downvotes ? The question is complete, understandable and rather well written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer to your problem:

Your code should be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, a, c;
    char ch;
    do
    {
        printf("Type the last number of the series 5 * 10 * 15 * ... * N:");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        getchar();   // absorb extra \n key from scanf, seem note below

        //   |< initialize a to 1 here, a needs to start from 1 each time
        //   |      |< initialize c to 5 here, c needs to start from 5 each time
        for (a = 1, c = 5 ; c <= n; a = a * c, c = c + 5)
        {
        }

        printf("The result is %d\nDo you want do it again? (Type 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no)", a);
        ch = getchar();
    }
    while (ch == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** `scanf` leaves an extra `\n` in the input buffer which is absorbed by the lone `getchar();`. Without that lone `getchar();` the `\n` would be absorbed by the `c = getchar();` below, thus putting `\n` into `ch`.

Comment: Good catch about `a` needing to be set to 1 each time.  Perhaps `c` also?

Comment: Agree this code meets OP's coding need, but is does not answer the "why" in the post's  title.

Comment: I was just wondering why my code worked when I used ;   for( ; c <= n; a = a*c, c = c +5).  I put the ; as a mistake. but that was the reason it worked just fine. I was not supposed to place a semicolon there, was I? But that's the reason it worked. explain please

Answer (score 1):

Completly unrelated to your problem, but I'm posting this as an answer because it's difficult to write this in a comment because of formatting limitations.

Following code (although correct apart from the getchar problem) looks as if the part between `{}` is part of the `for` loop because the `;` is easily missed and the `{}` is not necessary here.

```
for( ; c <= n; a = a*c, c = c +5);
{
  printf("The result is %d\nDo you want do it again? (Type 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no)", a);
  ch = getchar();
}
```

Write this rather like this:

```
for( ; c <= n; a = a*c, c = c +5)
{
}

printf("The result is %d\nDo you want do it again? (Type 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no)", a);
ch = getchar();
```

This makes it more clear that the loop is intentionally empty.

Answer (score 1):

firstly to those who are pointing an empty for loop...the ';' semicolon... it is intended...

secondly i am providing an alternative to it, which will solve the purpose though:-

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, a = 1, c = 5;
    char ch;
    do
    {
        printf("\nType the last number of the series 5 * 10 * 15 * ... * N:");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for( ; c <= n; a = a*c, c = c +5);
        printf("%d\nthe series is",a);
        printf("The result is %d\nDo you want do it again? (Type 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no)", a);
        ch=getch();

    }
    while(ch!='n');
    return 0;
}
```

this will do what i think you wanted to do...
Also i know there is difference between getch() and getchar() , but here i m just providing him an alternative solution...copy paste this code to compiler it will work

Comment: Thanks it works. But what was the mistake in my code? Besides that ";" I put was actually a mistake. But surprisingly that is why my code was working. Please explain

Comment: @FarhanFuad the reason was the \n was not being absorbed ... therefore your getchar() contained that \n...
also if it worked and liked the suugesstion on stack exchange then upvote it so that people get encouraged to answer it again